# How can I enable the Wifi Hotspot capability on my Moto Droid 1 without using Adhoc?

Tags: motorola-droid, wifi-hotspot

I want to enable the wifi access point / hotspot functionality on my Droid so it acts as a "Standard" router like the built in functionality of the newer VZW phones (like the Droid Incredible).  I have tried Wireless Tether for Root Users and Barnacle but they only create Adhoc connections for tethering which is different than becoming a hotspot.

My phone:

- Motorola Droid 1
- Rooted Android 2.2 w/ any ROM you tell me will get WAP going
- Verizon Wireless

**Edit:**  Just a preemptive request... Please don't suggest PDAnet.  Someone always does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This atrticle](http://www.cnet.com/8301-19736_1-20012378-251.html) and others around the same time suggest that the hardware in the Droid is only capable of supporting ad-hoc mode.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that unless you are running a different ROM (like CM6, etc.) then it's not available. Pretty sure stock ROM (rooted or not) didn't make this available (even though the non-stock ROMs had it working. Love how VZW said it wouldn't work when it obviously does.

Comment: I'm not sure it does. I haven't seen it confirmed anywhere. I'm running cm6.1 an still no wap. My ? is how do I make it work?